# Finding things with-in range

Tags: algorithm, server, range, game-engine, game-physics

I'm building my first online multiplayer game, and am trying to figure out the best way to find all players within range of a specific one.

I looked around; all other solutions are based off of game engine API's that have range-finding built in.

Each player has a raw `x,y` pair of co-ordinates.

The first thing I thought of, was: looping through every user on the server and filtering out those within range - simply using Pythagoras' theorem - however I knew there must be a better way to do it.

The best things I've thought of is splitting the map into sections of about 100 (10 x 10) and placing users into sections accordingly. I could then get the section the user is in, and instead of looping through every user on the server, loop through every user within 9 squares (3x3, the users section and all others surrounding it).

I'm sure this is better than simply looping through the whole server 1000 times a second but is there a standard way of doing it, or is this how its done?

I want to keep things lite both on the client and server side.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, what you thought of is asymptotically optimal since it's a constant number of operations per player unless they're all bunched up close to each other in the same quadrants.  In order to avoid allocating lots of memory for an array, you can use a (hashset / table / dictionary) and a hashing function that maps x, y to x / distance, y / distance so you can check whether the dictionary has the surrounding entries and then check the entries for players within distance of the player in question.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-V8fcYCG3s) talks about an almost isomorphic problem: hit detection with a bunch of circles.  Although in the video, you can't have a bunch of circles in the same spot.

If you're looking for simpler optimizations, you can first check whether the x and y of other players are each within the x and y of the player in question before checking that the sum of the square of the differences in x and y is less than the square of the distance you're checking for.

Some psudocode for this would be:

```
distance = 100
sections = {}

# initial setup
for player in players:
    section_x = player.x / distance
    section_y = player.y / distance
    index = [section_x, section_y]
    if !sections.get(index):
        sections[index] = []
    sections[index].push(player)

def players_near(player):
    nearby_players = []
    section_x = player.x / distance
    section_y = player.y / distance
    for section_dx in -1..1:
        for section_dy in -1..1:
            index = [section_x + section_dx, section_y + section_dy]
            players = sections[index]
            if players:
                nearby_players.extend(players)

    result = []
    for nearby_player in nearby_players:
        dx = abs(player.x - nearby_player.x)
        dy = abs(player.y - nearby_player.y)
        if dx <= distance and dy <= distance and sqr(dx) + sqr(dy) < sqr(distance):
            result.push(nearby_player)

    return result
```